# Laravel add old path when I try to use a resource

Tags: php, laravel

I created some resources with php artisan, located in Http/Resources/Api/V1
Then I moved all at the root folder : Http/Resources, and deleted the Api/V1 folders

But now, my application uses an old version of my resources, I dont know why.

For example, in my controller I have :

```
public function show($id)
{
    return new UserResource(User::findOrFail($id));
}
```

But the resource used is an old one, it doesn't even exists anymore

Comment: which version are you use in laravel?

Comment: I use the 5.6 laravel version

Comment: when you moved your resources did you change the namespace of the resources aswell? And after that did you change the includes at top of your controllers to reflect this change? If you did all that you need to run `composer du` to make sure they are autoloaded again.

Comment: Yes I changed the namespace in the resource, and updated in the controller too. The strange thing is, if I delete everything in my resource file, it still works and use an old resource that doesnt exist. If I delete the file, it returns an error of course. So it refers to the good file, but doesn't  use it

Comment: have you tried running composer dump-autoload

Comment: Yes nothing changes

Comment: Please see if `php artisan clear-compiled` and/or `php artisan config:clear` helps

Comment: I runned both, nothing changes, I still get an API return with missing information

Comment: did you update the namespace?

Answer (score 0):

When you moved your resources from `Http/Resources/Api/V1` to `Http/Resources` make sure you change the namespace in the resource files to reflect those changes.

After changing the namespaces make sure you use the correct includes  at the top of your controllers because they will be different after you changed your namespaces.

If you did all the above steps make sure to run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

This will fix any autoloading issues after you changed namespaces.

Comment: use App\Http\Resources\UserResource; use App\Http\Resources\UserResourceCollection; <- This is what there is in my controller

Comment: That is correct for the controller and inside the UserResource what is your namespace ?

Comment: namespace App\Http\Resources;

Comment: can you show the code inside the resource ? what info is missing and what have you provided ?